# How to programmatically init a subview whose constraints are based on its superview's bounds

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIview subclass whose constraints depend on its superview’s bounds. 
In the provided example, when my custom UIviews are initialized from Interface Builder, things are positioned as expected. However, when it is programmatically initialized from the viewController, the subviews are set up before the superview and their constraints are ignored.
Is there a way to initialize or update subviews layout once the superview’s bounds are known?

```
class CustomView: UIView {

let firstSubview = UIView()
let secondSubview = UIView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initialization()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialization()
}

func initialization() {

    firstSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    addSubview(firstSubview)
    firstSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    //....other autoLayout constraints for trailing, top and bottom anchors

    secondSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    addSubview(secondSubview)
    secondSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secondSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    //....other autoLayout constraints for trailing, top and bottom anchors 
    }
}
```

here is the viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let firstCustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    @IBOutlet weak var secondCustomView UIView! //working with autoLayout constraints from IB


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(firstCustomView)
    firstCustomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30)
    firstCustomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200)
    firstCustomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30)
    firstCustomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200)
    }
 }
```

EDIT: 
Here is the working code with proper constraints activation thanks to comments and help from @Sulthan.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  firstCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false view.addSubview(firstCustomView).isActive = true
  firstCustomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
  firstCustomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
  firstCustomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30).isActive = true
  firstCustomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -200).isActive = true 
}
```

Comment: This should work. Probably your constraints are ambigious or have another problem.

Comment: I added the full list of my constraints in viewDidLoad().  The problem might be there as the CustomView's constraints are working perfectly when the view is initialized from Interface Builder.

Comment: You are not activating the coinstraints

Comment: My bad, it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You only specify width constraint for the parent view

```
 firstCustomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2/3).isActive = true
```

you have to set other constraints like height and position (leading/trailing , top/bottom)

you can try

```
firstCustomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
firstCustomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant:20.0)
firstCustomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor , constant:30.0).isActive = true
firstCustomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2/3).isActive = true    
firstCustomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thank you.Indeed, trailing, top and bottom constraints are truncated in the code I shared, but they were present in the full version of my class, I am editing my first post to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use autoresizing masks:

```
firstCustomView.frame = frame
firstCustomView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
```

After that firstCustomView will properly resize to the viewController frame.